# reference module from outer folder

Tags: python, module

I have a module that I'm developing called "py_lopa".  typically, while developing it, I'll write a small script in the super-folder one layer up from "py_lopa" and run it from there.  however, this higher folder is getting cluttered with small files.

I'd like to somehow move the scripts to a subfolder that's at the same level as "py_lopa".  however, I'm unsure how to reference the py_lopa module from this other folder.

example structure:

```
"src_code" (highest level folder)
    "py_lopa" (sub-folder - contains entire module)
    "scripts_for_testing" (sub-folder - want to move all "test_script.py" files here)
    "test_script_001.py"
    "test_script_002.py"
    .
    .
    .
```

inside one of the test_script files, it currently imports py_lopa modules as needed:

```
from py_lopa.model_interface import Model_Interface
from py_lopa.data.tests_enum import Tests_Enum
from py_lopa.data.tables import Tables
.
.
.
```

however, if I move the test_script files to the "scripts_for_testing" folder, I can't reference the py_lopa module.

how can I reference the "py_lopa" module from a script inside the "scripts_for_testing" folder?

Comment: You can keep the working directory one level above at `src_code` and call the script as `py_lopa/scripts_for_testing/test_script_001.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sys.path.append(), like below.
The assumption is that py_lopa folder is exactly one level up.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from py_lopa.model_interface import Model_Interface

print(sys.modules.keys())
```

Below is the files structure and the outputs. Notice that you can execute the test.py scripts from whatever path/location you want.

```
~/work_area/python/tmp :-)> tree .
.
|-- py_lopa
|   `-- model_interface
|       `-- Model_Interface.py
`-- scripts_for_testing
    `-- test.py
3 directories, 2 files

~/work_area/python/tmp :-)> python3 scripts_for_testing/test.py
dict_keys(['builtins', 'sys', '_frozen_importlib', '_imp', '_warnings', '_thread', '_weakref', '_frozen_importlib_external', '_io', 'marshal', 'posix', 'zipimport', 'encodings', 'codecs', '_codecs', 'encodings.aliases', 'encodings.utf_8', '_signal', '__main__', 'encodings.latin_1', 'io', 'abc', '_weakrefset', 'site', 'os', 'errno', 'stat', '_stat', 'posixpath', 'genericpath', 'os.path', '_collections_abc', '_sitebuiltins', 'sysconfig', '_sysconfigdata_m_linux_x86_64-linux-gnu', 'py_lopa', 'py_lopa.model_interface', 'py_lopa.model_interface.Model_Interface'])

~/work_area/python/tmp :-)> cd scripts_for_testing

~/work_area/python/tmp/scripts_for_testing :-)> python3 test.py
dict_keys(['builtins', 'sys', '_frozen_importlib', '_imp', '_warnings', '_thread', '_weakref', '_frozen_importlib_external', '_io', 'marshal', 'posix', 'zipimport', 'encodings', 'codecs', '_codecs', 'encodings.aliases', 'encodings.utf_8', '_signal', '__main__', 'encodings.latin_1', 'io', 'abc', '_weakrefset', 'site', 'os', 'errno', 'stat', '_stat', 'posixpath', 'genericpath', 'os.path', '_collections_abc', '_sitebuiltins', 'sysconfig', '_sysconfigdata_m_linux_x86_64-linux-gnu', 'py_lopa', 'py_lopa.model_interface', 'py_lopa.model_interface.Model_Interface'])
```